# extract birth day, month, year separately from Facebook sdk

Tags: php

I'm using the Facebook SDK to get a user's birthday, which returns a string in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format. How would I get the **day, month and year** separately so that I can have `$day`, `$month`, and `$year` instead of just one birthday string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `explode` function.

```
$date_arr = explode('/', $date);
echo $date_arr[0].'/'.$date_arr[1].'/'.$date_arr[2];

// Output: mm/dd/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `explode()` using `/`,

```
 list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);

  echo $day." " .$month." ".$year;
```